# DataTables issue with pagination

Tags: php, datatables

### Problem

I am using DataTables with server-side processing. I have an issue with pagination.

I have **Show 10 entries** selected and page 1 shows:

> Showing 1 to 10 of 12,948 entries

and 10 rows but once I go to page 2 it shows:

> Showing 11 to 20 of 12,948 entries

but 11 rows.

### Script

Here is the section of the PHP script used in server-side processing that I think is where the problem lies:

```
    $betweenLower = intval($data['start']);
    $betweenUpper = intval($data['start'] + $data['length']);


    $dataOut = dt_oci_exec( $conn, $bindings, <<<EOD
        SELECT a.*
        FROM (
            SELECT rownum rnum, b.*
            FROM (
                SELECT $select
                FROM $tables
                $where
                $orderBy
            ) b
            WHERE rownum <= $betweenUpper
        ) a
        WHERE rnum >= $betweenLower
EOD
    );

    $filterCount = dt_oci_exec( $conn, $bindings, <<<EOD
        SELECT COUNT(*) as COUNT
        FROM $tables
        $where
        $orderBy
EOD
    );

    $fullCount = dt_oci_exec( $conn, $bindings, <<<EOD
        SELECT COUNT(*) as COUNT
        FROM $tables
        $whereJoinOnly
EOD
    );
```

Please can someone help me understand why it is showing 11 rows on subsequent pages when only 10 rows should be shown?

Comment: Without a jsfiddle reproducing the problem, or a link to a page actually showing 11 records on page #2 and forth, I must admit I really do not believe dataTables show 11 rows :)

Comment: Is it something as simple as `$data['start'] = 1` &  `$data['length'] = 10`, therefore `betweenUpper =11`

Comment: Reproduce the problem in an example and I'll believe you.